# How to convert a specific type to a generic type

Tags: c#, oop, templates, inheritance

I've got the following classes:

- Parameter.cs (generic type)
- CurrentLod.cs (specific type, inherits from Parameter)

This is the current class definition for Parameter.cs

```
public abstract class Parameter<T> where T: IComparable{
     // class methods...
}
```

And then the class definition for CurrentLod.cs

```
public class CurrentLod : Parameter<String>{
     
     // Constructor
     public CurrentLod() : base()
}
```

Then, in a third file

```
new List<Parameter<IComparable>>() { new CurrentLod() }
```

The previous code won't compile, and the compiler shows the error message: "Cannot convert from CurrentLod to Parameter"

I believe it's got something to do with covariance and contravariance, but it's still not clear to me.

Comment: @TimSchmelter what could be a good alternative ? I need Parameter as the parent class that represents any type of parameter, the important thing here, is that children can be of type integer/string/currency (float) etc...

I need that flexibility in order to work with a high level API of an Autodesk software, that handles its own types (physical units, currencies, text, etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `List<T>` is defined to accept any `Parameter<IComparable>`. `CurrentLod` is a specific type of `Parameter<IComparable>`, namely a `Parameter<String>`.

We might later define another type `Foo : Parameter<Int32>`, since `Int32` also implements `IComparable`.

But what does it mean to add a `Foo` to a list of `CurrentLod`s?

To address your question, you could create a non-generic base class or interface for your parameter type and use that as the type of your List, e.g.:

```
public abstract class Parameter
{
    // Common paramater operations/properties. This could be an interface.
}

public class Parameter<T> : Parameter where T : IComparable
{
    // Type-specific generic members.
}

public class Int32Parameter : Parameter<Int32>
{
    // Int32 Parameter implementation
}

public class StringParameter : Parameter<String>
{
    // String Parameter implementation
}

// This unit test will compile and pass
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var l = new List<Parameter>();
        l.Add(new StringParameter());
        l.Add(new Int32Parameter());

        Assert.Equal(2, l.Count);
    }
}
```

Now the List is defined to contain a single, specific type. When you retrieve an item from the list, you'll need to test what its concrete type is and cast it appropriately.

Comment: I get your point. What i'm trying to achieve here, is to define a generic Parameter class that is flexible enough to accept some primitive types of c# (string, int, float,  for now) and modify its behavior accordingly. Then create a list of all these parameters to work with them as needed. Is it possible to achieve that level of flexibility with templates ?